# Passport scanner problem

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, south-korea

I have a question and concern on the passport scanner issue.

It happened at South Korea airport.

Before I went to luggage inspection, I have to scan the passport with airport staff and when my passport was being scanned, there was warning sound or weird sound from the passport reader machine. It was a different sound from other people before me. And staff just handed a passport to me normally. And then I went to luggage inspection normally.

My question: does this situation happen normally, and there is nothing on my passport right?

Comment: If you have an Android phone, could you try scanning the passport using the app [ReadID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.innovalor.nfciddocshowcase "ReadID - NFC Passport Scanner") and tell us the result?

Comment: The other answer does not explain why other peaple get another noise. It assumes that this noise always occurs.

Comment: If you do automatic ID check, you will find that sometime machine star reading too early, or the passport is not correctly placed, or just you moved the passport before the scan. This happens also airport staff side. If they didn't check further, it seems just a normal error. If you were tracked (e.g. as criminal), either you would be blocked and asked more questions, or you will not know [no weird sound, not to alarm you].